# Decompile / Reverse Engineer ASPX Web Application

Tags: asp.net, reverse-engineering, decompiling

Wondering if anyone has a recommended solution to decompile a single asps page to see the code behind.  This is a web application we use internally within our organisation but don't have the project solution.  The project developers have since gone bust and we now have zero support.

I've seen dotPeek and .NET Reflector but any tutorial i've seen all seems to be around exe applications and not .NET web applications.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should just be able to grab the DLL's and decompile them. The code for individual pages will be in individual classes. Did you try that?

Comment: the DLL's in the App_Data and BIN Folder?

Comment: There shouldn't be DLL's in App_Data. You should have a single DLL in bin for your website's code, then other DLL's for other assemblies you've referenced.

Comment: thanks mason, was able to use the DLL and find what i needed.  much appreciated. for info i used ilspy.